# Showing List of combobox while getting focus (vb.net)

Tags: vb.net, drop-down-menu

When we click on drop down combobox control in our windows form, it shows the list automatically.

But when we press tab and navigate to that control from keyboard it doesn't shows the list automatically. So in other to show the list automatically on receiving focus what should be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the DroppedDown property of the combobox  equal to true.

```
    Private Sub myComboBox_GotFocus(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles myComboBox.GotFocus
 myComboBox.DroppedDown= true
    End Sub
```

Comment: I wanted to mention that using this on focus or enter then if the user clicks the down arrow on the combobox it will open and close again immediately (bug?).  To avoid this I used click event, as it still suited my needs (although this means that the user can't click the combobox text to select where to type)

Answer (score 0):

I would like to mention on thing here.

I used Enter event to show Drop down list with DroppedDown=true,

But When I type something in text area of combobox and if i leave the area to next control, entered text is lost.

My combobox is databound.